# modify shortcode atts(), is that possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, posts

i use link shortcode on my template functions.php like this,

```
function post_link_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'kelime' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
    if ( isset( $id ) ) {
        return '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="' . $id  . '"> <strong>' .$kelime  . '</strong></a>';
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'link', 'post_link_shortcode' );
```

**Usage :** 
[link id="someurl.com" kelime="link title"]

could we change this like; 
[link|someurl.com|link title]

is that possible ? than how ? thanks.

Comment: Please, [read the notes](http://www.php.net/extract) and _don't use extract_. Just use objects or, if needs must, an array and _type-hinting_

Comment: In wordpress they give details about shortcode API Read here  [API For SHORTCODE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)